# ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timezone

I'm accessing an Oracle Database from a java application, when I run my application I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>   ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

Comment: Tell us about your environment, how do you run your java ?

Comment: I'm running the Java application on the command line. Windows 7 64bit, but Oracle DB is running on a remote Unix server.

Comment: try to add "-Duser.timezone=<YOUR_GMT>" to your command, don't forget to replace <YOUR_GMT> with your GMT, ie -Duser.timezone="+05:30"

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You may also try to check the version of the Oracle jdbc driver and Oracle database. Just today I had this issue when using ojdbc6.jar (version 11.2.0.3.0) to connect to an Oracle 9.2.0.4.0 server. Replacing it with ojdbc6.jar version 11.1.0.7.0 solved the issue.

I also managed to make ojdbc6.jar version 11.2.0.3.0 connect without error, by adding `oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false` in file oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties (inside the jar). Found this solution [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1095807) (broken link)

Then, one can add `-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false` to the command line, or `AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false` in config files that use this notation.

You can also do this programmatically, e.g. with `System.setProperty`.

In some cases you can add the environment variable on a per-connection basis if that's allowed (SQL Developer allows this in the "Advanced" connection properties; I verified it to work when connecting to a database that doesn't have the problem and using a database link to a database which has).

Comment: I also managed to make ojdbc6.jar version 11.2.0.3.0 connect without error, by adding oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false in file oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties (inside the jar). Found this solution here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1095807

Comment: Lastly, one can add
-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
to the command line, or AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false in config files that use this notation.

Comment: Thanks stmsat. It worked for me. I changed my ojdbc jar to 11.1.0.7.0 version in tomcat/lib directory and it started working :).

Comment: I am using maven to build and package(war) my project and deploy in Cloud Flare, is there any way setting this property can be done from *application.properties* file or from maven.

Comment: Or maybe you can change system timezone, that worked for me (e.g. sudo timedatectl set-timezone you_zone)

Answer (score 48):

In a plain a SQL-Developer installation under Windows go to directory

```
C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin
```

and add

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=CET
```

to file `sqldeveloper.conf`.

Comment: Using Jetbrains DataGrip and faced the same issue after adding this VM Option the problem was solved

Comment: Thanks, this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 29):

Error I got :

Error from db_connection.java -->> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
 ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

Prev code:

```
 public Connection getOracle() throws Exception {
     Connection conn = null;
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:tap", "username", "pw");
     return conn;
}
```

new Code:

```
 public Connection getOracle() throws Exception {
     TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
     TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
     Connection conn = null;
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:tap", "username", "pw");
     return conn;
}
```

now it is working!!

Comment: I don't know why it did not like the default timezone 'Europe/Madrid'. Setting the default timezone to 'GMT' works.

Answer (score 24):

Update the file *oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties* in whatever version of the library (i.e. inside your jar) you are using to contain the line below:

```
oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```

Answer (score 21):

What happens is, that the JDBC client sends the timezone ID to the Server. The server needs to know that zone. You can check with

```
SELECT DISTINCT tzname FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES where tzname like 'Etc%';
```

I have some db servers which know about 'Etc/UTC' and 'UTC' (tzfile version 18) but others only know 'UTC' (tz version 11).

```
SELECT FILENAME,VERSION from V$TIMEZONE_FILE;
```

There is also different behavior on the JDBC client side. Starting with 11.2 the driver will sent the zone IDs if it is "known" to Oracle, whereas before it sent the time offset. The problem with this "sending of known IDs" is, that the client does not check what timezone version/content is present on the server but has its own list.

This is explained in Oracle Support Article [ID 1068063.1].

It seems it also depends on the Client OS, it was more likely that Etc/UTC fails with Ubuntu than RHEL or Windows. I guess this is due to some normalization but I haven't figured out what exactly.

Answer (score 18):

1. in eclipse go **run** - > **run configuration**
2. in there go to **JRE** tab in right side panels
3. in **VM Arguments** section paste this

   `-Duser.timezone=GMT`
4. then Apply - > Run

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem when running automated tests from a continuous integration server. I tried adding the VM argument "`-Duser.timezone=GMT`" to the build parameters, but that didn't solve the problem. However, adding the environment variable "`TZ=GMT`" did fix it for me.

Comment: The "TZ=GMT" environment variable also worked for me. I was having problems with a shell script that set up the environment for running a separate tool that, in turn, accessed Oracle.

Comment: Having the same issue, I too had to use "TZ=Europe/Zurich" when using "ant". It worked!

Comment: This should be the top answer. All other answers didn't work.

Comment: in docker this worked for me `TZ=America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: Adding TZ=IST worked for me when jenkins build located in GMT+2 was trying to access database located in India.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem with Tomcat.  Setting the following in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` solved the issue:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```

I'm sure that using one of the Java parameter suggestions from the other answers would work in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

ERROR :

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Solution:
CIM setup in Centos.

```
/opt/oracle/product/ATG/ATG11.2/home/bin/dynamoEnv.sh
```

Add this java arguments:

```
JAVA_ARGS="${JAVA_ARGS} -Duser.timezone=EDT"
```

Answer (score 3):

In Netbeans,

1. Right-click your project -> Properties
2. Go to Run (under Categories)
3. Enter -Duser.timezone=UTC or -Duser.timezone=GMT under VM Options.

Click Ok, then re-run your program.

Note: You can as well set to other timestones besides UTC & GMT.

Answer (score 3):

If this problem is in JDeveloper:
Change the project properties for both the model and the view project -> run/debug -> default profile -> edit
add the following run option:
-Duser.timezone=Asia/Calcutta

Make sure that the above time zone value is fetched from your database as follows:

```
select TZNAME from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

Along with that you'd want to check the time zone settings in your jdev.conf as well as in the JDeveloper -> Application Menu -> Default Project Propertes -> Run/Debug -> Default Profile -> Run Options.

Answer (score 2):

**I also same faced similar issue.**

#### **Environment:**

Linux, hibernate project, ojdbc6 driver while querying oracle 11g database.

#### Resolution

TZ parameter was not set in linux machine, that basically tell oracle about the timezone.
So, After adding export statment "export TZ=UTC" at time of application start solved my problem.

UTC--> Change accorind to your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when trying to make a connection on OBIEE to Oracle db.
I changed my Windows timezone from (GMT+01:00) West Central Africa to (GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris. Then I rebooted my computer and it worked just fine.
Seems like Oracle was not able to recognize the west central Africa timezone.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens as the code which is trying to connect to db, has a timezone which is not in db.
It can also be resolved by setting the time zone as below or any valid time zone available in oracle db. 
valid time zone which can be found select * from v$version;

System.setProperty("user.timezone", "America/New_York");
TimeZone.setDefault(null);

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem when i tried to create connection in JDeveloper. Our server located in different timezone and hence it raised the below errors as:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 

ORA-01882: timezone region not found
```

I referred many forums which asked to include timezone in the Java Options(Run/Debug/Profile) of Project properties and Default Project properties as `-Duser.timezone="+02:00"` bBut it didn't work for me. Finally the following solution worked for me.

Add the following line to the JDeveloper's configuration file (*jdev.conf*).

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=UTC+02:00
```

The file is located in "<oracle installation root>\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdev.conf".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the same issue by setting the timezone in my linux system (Centos6.5).

Reposting from

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

1. set timezone in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` e.g. set to ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"
2. sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix /etc/localtime

To figure out the timezone value try to

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

and look for the file that represents your timezone.

Once you've set these reboot the machine and try again.

Comment: For me, making sure that /etc/sysconfig/clock and the /etc/localtime link were set properly was basically a prerequisite for solving the ORA-01882 issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could get the query working by changing "TZR" with "TZD"..

```
String query = "select * from table1 to_timestamp_tz(origintime,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZD') between ?  and ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue using Eclipse and a distant Oracle Database, changing my **system time zone** to match the time zone of the database server fixed the problem.
**Re-start the machine** after changing system time zone.

I hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL
>   level 1 ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

For this type of error, just change your system time to your country's standard GMT format

e.g. Indian time zone is chennai,kolkata.

Answer (score 0):

Happens when you use the wrong version of OJDBC jar.

You need to use
11.2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i set the timezone at my OS level (ubuntu) with this command.

> timedatectl set-timezone {timezone}

For example,

```
timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Kampala
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but It may help someone.
I encountered this issue while working on spring-boot application and failed to connect to the Oracle DB.

Error:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-01882: timezone region not found

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual; -- This return: +00:00
timedatectl #The OS on the other hand returned correct time and timezone
```

Since I am not a system admin and not allowed to change system config, I had to apply a workaround in the codes.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
#Added the above into the application property file
```

The working solution came from the below link

[Working solution URL](https://www.javafixing.com/2022/07/fixed-how-to-set-servertimezone-in.html)

*Edit*

---

After the DBA patched the oracle with the missing timezone patches, The above (...timezoneAsRegion=false) was no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

**For Spring-Boot Application - // add below two lines**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class  Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // add below two lines
      System.out.println("Setting the timezone"+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00").getID());
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+9:00"));
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```