# Can not connect oracle 10g personal edition r2 database using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i tried to perform connection test on netbeans as by creating new connection from databases node.

i am trying to connect with `ojdbc6.jar` driver and my `sid` of databse is `orcl` (oracle personal edition).

while creating new connection i did locate the oracle thin driver, used port `1521`, i am using `hr` user which i have unlocked previously, the connection string of my connection is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl` but when i perform testing it throws message

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection),

need help ,thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you connect using SQL*Plus? Are you sure you started the Oracle instance **and** the listener?

Comment: yes , i did started the services ! and it works fine with SQL*Plus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was easy ! 
just do not forgot to conform your database connection string.

as in figure ,
if u filled fields like HOST , PORT , SID then ti will change the connection string that is generated automatically,

it was my simple mistake which bother me for one week ! thanks lot for everyone who guided me and specially  for @Stanley!

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that the Oracle service is running, next I think you need to try ojdbc14.

Comment: yes server is running ! and it connects on manual code ! but when i try to connect with making new connection from database node  of #netbeans service tab ! it throws `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01882: timezone region not found` @Stanley

Comment: Like I said you may need to change the OJDBC jar to match with your Oracle Version. See this Answer for more Information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: yes i did used another driver still it is throwing the same mgs ! @Stanley