# exception while trying to upgrade oto ojdbc7.jar from ojdb6.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, ojdbc

I swapped out my ojdb6.jar file in tomcat/lib with ojdb7.jar. Turned on Tomcat and I get the following error when trying to use it...

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
```

here is the connection pool configuration I am using....

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    maxActive="25" maxIdle="25" maxWait="2000" 
    name="jdbc/getcontacts" 
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1000" 
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="30000" 
    logAbandoned="true" 
    username="xxxx" password="xxxxx" 
    validationQuery="Select 1 from dual" connectionProperties="defaultRowPrefetch=10000" 
    url="jdbcracle:thin:@//xxxxx.net/xxxxx" />
```

Any idea what could be causing this? We are using Oracle database 11g.

```
/usr/jdk7/bin/java -version 
java version "1.7.0_17" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. When I put the ojdb6.jar file back and remove the ojdb7.jar file everything works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: Why the downvote?  I searched for ojdbc7 and did not come across this.

Comment: If someone now does a similar upgrade to ojdb7 and they get this problem and search for ojdbc upgrade then they will come across this post and it might help them.  This is the context in which I asked the question, basically why did the change cause this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding VM arg

```
-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```

Comment: Wow it worked.  You genius you.  Can you explain what that did?

Comment: @Jose: read the post Jay linked to in the comments, the explanation is there.

Comment: I googled and found the property setting to turn that feature off.  I can't really claim to be a genius.

Comment: @Nathan, none of those comments go over ojdb7.jar.

Comment: Look here in the API docs.  I don't know which version of Oracle you're using so I guessed.  That setting hasn't changed much.

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_TIMEZONE_AS_REGION