# Getting ORA-01882: timezone region not found with Oracle UCP, on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timezone, ucp

I am running a springboot application (which is running fine on local machine), and getting `ORA-01882: timezone region not found` error on ec2 instance. Its looks like a config problem but not sure how to fix it.

Stack trace is below

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to start the Universal
>   Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot
>   get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: 
>   ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>
> ORA-01882: timezone region not found

I am using ojdbc8 version 12.2.0.1

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: Add details of the version of the DB and the driver you are using, this will help figure out the problem.

Comment: Since I was already on 12.2.0.1 version, the version fix provided was not really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass command line argument `-Duser.timezone=<Database Time Zone>` to start the application.

Example:

Maven Command line: `mvn springboot:run -Duser.timezone=PST`

Java Command line: `java -Duser.timezone=PST -jar application.jar`

Here are the timezones list.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones