# Springboot unable to determine JDBC url from datasource while deploying application in PCF(Pivotal Cloud Foundary)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am deploying SpringBoot application in PCF which has oracle database connection i  have also made user created service instance with oracle credentials and binded to application.

Following is the VCAP service variables :

**{

          "name": "healthwatch-api-database",

          "instance_name": "healthwatch-api-database",

          "binding_name": null,

          "credentials": {

            "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",

            "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=10.157.129.175)(PORT=1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=DEVCLOUD)))",

            "username": "EXTRANET_USER",

            "password": "EXTRANET_USER1"

          },**

Following are the logs after pushing application :

2018-10-09T18:26:41.29+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT                  o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
   2018-10-09T18:26:41.47+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 09 Oct 2018 12:56:41.471/UTC [main] INFO

2018-10-09T18:26:41.47+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT                             o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 09 Oct 2018 12:56:42.174/UTC [main] WARN

2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT                               o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is **org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1**

2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ORA-01882: timezone region not found

2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:338)

Comment: @ K.AJ could you please help.

Comment: Ensure that you read the `JDBC  Connection` details from the `CUPS` you created and then have that Injected properly in your Spring Boot App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error log, the cause seems to be related to timezone settings.

`2018-10-09T18:26:42.17+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ORA-01882: timezone region not found`

Here is a post talking about a similar issue - [Getting ORA-01882: timezone region not found with Oracle UCP, on aws ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492093/getting-ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found-with-oracle-ucp-on-aws-ec2-instanc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now how do you pass the timezone to your app?

You do that through manifest file. Check out the article - 
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! It helped me