# How to connect to Oracle 9i using ojdbc7.jar?

Tags: oracle12c, oracle9i, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle 9i DB using the ojdbc7.jar. But I am getting the below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:762)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:422)
    at com.sunil.test.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

I am firing a simple query "select * from dual". The code works fine if I switch to older jar like classes12.jar.

Is there any way I can connect to 9i using ojdbc7.jar?

Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to : [ORA-01882: timezone region not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found/22761437#22761437)

I launch the JVM with the option "-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false" and We manage to conenct to a Oracle 9i database using Oracle 11 driver for Java 6 (ojdbc6.jar)