# uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM AH_PATIENT]; SQL state [60000]; error code [604]; ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb, pcf, pcfdev

I am deploying the **Spring Boot - Spring Batch** code on the PCF DEV environment, where batch code will connect to Oracle Dev and load all data into mongo dev. But while `>cf push`, I am getting below error.

```
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 45 common frames omitted
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:149) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:427) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.initializeConnection(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:458) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Executing query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM AH_PATIENT]; SQL state [60000]; error code [604]; ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [app/:na]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [app/:na]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app/:na]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app/:na]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
2019-06-04T10:12:43.319+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
```

I followed link: [ORA-01882: timezone region not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found/22761437), but where to exactly changed I am not aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using link: [ORA-01882: timezone region not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found/22761437).

I just set `-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false` in `manifest.yml` file. You can also manually add user defined environment variables in PCF.