# Getting an error while connection to Oracle Database in Spring boot

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, ojdbc

I have an oracle database 10g,
I am using Spring Boot 2.5.5, JPA.

When i execute this

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL
```

i get **+00:00**
My pom is the below:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
    </properties>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
        
        
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           
        </dependency>
        <!--Jpa-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--data rest-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Tymeleaf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Mysql-->
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Lombok-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--hateoas-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--javax-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!--Database
        -
        -
        -
        -
        -
        
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Mysql-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>

                  
        
                    
        <!--Hikari helps in connection pools-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <finalName>
                warehouse
            </finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

My Application.properties is:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.92.5:1521/ORADB
spring.datasource.username=magerwa
spring.datasource.password=butare
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I tried this to configure like this:

```
   @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("+00:00"));
        }
```

but none worked for me

Comment: Where is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion' in value "${oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion}"

Comment: Any suggestion dear James Z

Comment: Unfortunately no, but there's for example a lot of different suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest JDBC driver from 19.15