# How to set serverTimeZone in Oracle JDBC database URL?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, ojdbc

I'm getting an error when I try to start a spring-boot application with Oracle connection:

```
csm-security              | 2022-06-29 19:26:21.571  INFO [csm-security,,] 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2402 ms
csm-security              | 2022-06-29 19:26:22.329  INFO [csm-security,,] 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
csm-security              | 2022-06-29 19:26:23.847 ERROR [csm-security,,] 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
...
csm-security              | java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
csm-security              | ORA-01882: timezone region not found
```

I've tried to put **useTimezone** and **serverTimezone** on my application.properties but it didn't work:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.1..1.1:1521:desastg?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

I've also tried to put this:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found

Comment: I'd like to change on jdbc-url as I do on MySql. I don't want to change my application. @Toerktumlare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My server timezone was:

Command: *timedatectl*

```
Time zone: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires (-03, -0300)
```

And in Oracle was:

Sql:*SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual;*

```
+00:00
```

So I have to change on application.properties to put timezoneAsRegion to false:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```

According to Oracle documentation when timezoneAsRegion is set to true it uses default JVM timezone rather than convert to a GMT offset.